# Android navigation component popup to home screen when open the app by deeplink

Tags: android, navigation, deep-linking

I'm developing an app and using **navigation component** to navigate between screens.

I have this problem when I open my app using a deep link and want to popup to my home screen when the user pressed **back button**.

The graph is like this:

```xml
<navigation startDestination="@id/starter" >
    <fragment id="@+id/starter" />
    <fragment id="@+id/home" />
    <fragment id="@+id/profile" >
      <deepLink uri="app://profile" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And this is the scenario:

Click on link ***https//domain.com/app/profile*** -> app opens -> **starter fragment** receives the intent data -> navigate to **profile** -> the back button pressed -> **app closes** // here I want to navigate back to my home screen.

I also set **popUpTo** parameter, but it **doesn't work**:

```kotlin
navController.navigate(
    uri,
    NavOptions.Builder()
              .setPopUpTo(R.id.home, false).build()
)
```